# How to "reencode" mp3 files

Tags: audio, mp3

I have a fair number of mp3 files which I created using audiohijack pro on a mac.  Now I no longer have a mac and am using them on my linux systems.  Unfortunately the program I use (rhythmbox) to listen to these files cannot figure out how long the files are.  These files are up to 5 hours long, and when the program cannot figure out how long it is I can't scroll through the file.  Any unix/linux programs that can reencode these files?  I do not know enough about either audio on linux or the mp3 file format to know what would be involved in this.

Best,
Bart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not answer the question in your title, but maybe there's a chance to fix the files without reencoding. For example, one common issue with incorrect lengths of MP3 files are files with variable bit rate that are not properly marked as having a variable bit rate (and programs like rhythmbox treating them as if they had a constant one). The tool [vbrfix](http://home.gna.org/vbrfix/) can fix those files. Another useful tool to check the MP3 file is [mp3check](http://jo.ath.cx/soft/mp3check/), it also has options like `--fix-headers` that might repair the files (make backups of the files first!).

Comment: Nice.  This seems like a very useful tool.

Comment: "for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do vbrfix -always -log EndersGame$i.mp3 EG$i.mp3; done"

was the command I used to save on some typing.

Comment: i really don't understand why linking to a crappy program developed on windows and only later ported to linux (hence not even scriptable, tsk tsk) made this the accepted answer! (so i downvoted the answer)

Comment: @ixtmixilix - For vbrfix atleast, the binaries they have compile on the link are for windowz as that it what many ppl sadly use. Versions for Linux are available elsewhere ([and also appears to be included in Ubuntu 12.04+](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vbrfix)) - you can also try using the available [source code](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/vbrfix/trunk/vbrfix/). The mp3check link is dead though....

Comment: OK vbrfix works perfectly - as I use Fedora, I downloaded the [sources for the Ubuntu version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/vbrfix), used `dpkg-source -x vbrfix_0.24-7.dsc` to extract it, apply patches etc, then `./configure --prefix='/home/wilf/Downloads/fsbOPEN/vbrfix/makeinstall'`, `make` and `make install` to produce a standalone excitable that I could use on my files. I needed to parse the `-always` option to make it work.

Answer (score 10):

While I do not know specifically whether additional options would be needed to fix the issue you mention, [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is

> a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.

It is the swiss-army knife for audio and video.  Re-encoding your files should be as easy as

```
$ ffmpeg -i oldfile.mp3 newfile.mp3
```

`ffmpeg` is in the repositories of most major distributions or it can be downloaded from their website.

Comment: this seems like a more sane answer to me. obviously the OP has a lot of files and probably knows how to open a command line, though one worries these days, and  as a matter of fact this answer actually answered the question i was about to ask. so i upvoted it. you acquire good SE karma, @Steven D, though your answer got no votes until i saw it.

Comment: I have a similar issue, and already tried ffmpeg and it for the most part worked :D, but have a few files on which it exited citing `Invalid data found when processing input`....

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do it with `lame` and carry over the id3 tags (found it [here](http://terminallinux.org/p/84/)).

```
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3" | while read file 
do
    mv "$file" "${file}.old" && \
    lame --mp3input -q 0 -b 192 --resample 44.1 "${file}.old" "$file" && \
    id3cp "${file}.old" "$file"
done
```

See more conversion scripts I have writtten here: https://github.com/sid-the-sloth/conversion-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) I should warn you that re-encoding may (probably) result in quality loss.